# How to make a link to show all data

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, visual-studio-2010, linq

I would like to make a task as follow: show the data as links, I only show 3 rows at beginning, so I Take(3). Then, I want a link "Show all", and when I click on it, it will show the rest of data.

I don't know how to do that. Can anyone help me.
Thanks in advance.

Detail.aspx.cs

```
vertragsnehmer.DataSource = vertrag.Vertragsnehmer.Take(3).Select(x=> new { x.Id, Name = x.GetFullName(), Typ = x.GetType().Name });
vertragsnehmer.DataBind();
```

Detail.aspx

```
<asp:Repeater ID="vertragsnehmer" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
         <td>
             <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl='<%# "~/Redirect.aspx?Id=" + Eval("Id") + "&Typ=" + Eval("Typ") %>' Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>  
         </td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

place linkbutton on apsx page:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="ShowALL" runat="server" onclick="ShowAll_Click">Show All</asp:LinkButton>
```

on .cs file:

```
protected void ShowAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  vertragsnehmer.DataSource = vertrag.Vertragsnehmer.Select(x=> new { x.Id, Name = x.GetFullName(), Typ = x.GetType().Name });
  vertragsnehmer.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I did try this before, but it didn't work as intended. I want to show 3 records, and click ShowAll LinkButton, then the rest of records will apprear, it's like re-render, but I don't know how to do that. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make showAll button postback and rebind the grid with everything in the onCLick event?

Comment: Hi, the requirement is that, I show 3 records as links, then comes another link Show All, which will show the rest of the records when clicked. not a button